# Namespaces and traits

Tags: php, namespaces, traits

I'm getting an error using traits and namespaces, beacuse the trait can not be found.

index.php:

```
require_once 'src/App.php';
use App\main;

$App = new App();
```

src/App.php

```
namespace App\main;
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'DataBase.php';
/**
 * code
 */
```

src/DataBase.php

```
namespace App\DataBase;

require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Singleton.php';

class DataBase {
  use Singleton; // or use App\Singleton

  /**
   * code
   */
}
```

src/Singleton.php

```
namespace App\Singleton.php;
trait Singleton {
  /**
   * code
   */
}
```

But, when I run that from Index.php, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'App\DataBase\Singleton' not found in (...)
```

How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

Php automatically set the class name in the namespace, for example:

Bar.php

```
namespace App;
class Bar {
  /**
   * code
   */
}
```

The, when you call this package, you can use App\Bar, this means that the classes is setted by default.

Comment: `use App\main` in `index.php` does nothing. `App\main` is a namespace, not a symbol name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't importing (or *use*-ing in PHP parlance) the `App\Singleton\Singleton` symbol in your `App\DataBase` namespace so PHP assumes that `Singleton` is in the same namespace.

In `src/DataBase.php`...

```
namespace App\DataBase;

use App\Singleton\Singleton;

require_once __DIR__ . '/Singleton.php';

class DataBase {
    use Singleton;

    // and so on
```

Also, I highly recommend you implement an autoloader strategy (preferably PSR-0) to avoid all the `require_once` calls.

#### Update

To clarify, when you do this...

```
namespace App\DataBase;

class DataBase { ... }
```

The full name of this class is `\App\DataBase\DataBase`. The `namespace` declaration does not include the class / trait names.

Comment: There's a way to replace this?
I want to use Package\class instead of Package\class\class

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez They're your classes. If you want `Singleton` to be in the `App` namespace instead of the `App/Singleton` namespace, then simply change it. Same goes for `DataBase` in the `App/DataBase` namespace.